# Getting back results without iterating with new PHP MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb

Something I can't seem to figure out with the new MongoDB driver and package is how to figure out how many results are returned, if any, after a query runs, without looping through all of them. With the old driver, I would have just used `->count()`, but now that an iterator is returned, the only thing I can think of is to use the toArray() function if the `count($return->toArray())` is non-zero.

Is there any other/better way?

Comment: did you try that whats the issue ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using, I'm just trying to get a better understanding of the new package, to see if there's another, better method that I didn't notice. Casting to an array and then counting seems like a strange method of figuring out how many results come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new driver will return MongoCursor. Please use [MongoCursor count](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.count.php) to retrieve the total number of records. I hope this is a little old issue you would be using a recent mongo-php-driver

Please see

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/178

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/195

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/195#issuecomment-169405194

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found those answers, but when I run $count on the returning cursor, I get a method not found error, though I'm using the latest driver and package. Maybe some other error? I donno, I'll look into it, but I'm glad that I was on the right track. Thanks a lot!